# .net get value of input type "hidden" in ashx

Tags: .net, asp.net, hidden-field

I need to now how to get a value of a input type="hidden" in a ashx page.

Anyone can help me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `runat="server"` in the `input` and assign an `id`.  You can then use the `id` in your code behind.

There is another method.  Using the `asp:HiddenField`.  A video can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-use-a-hidden-field-to-store-and-manipulate-client-side-information).

Comment: I have the runat="server" and the id. in the ashx when i try form["myid"] it is null... I will try with the asp:HiddenField

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using "ashx" instead of "aspx"? As far as I know, ASHX is for Http Handlers, not web pages.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using a asp:HiddenField.
in my ashx page in catch the value of the hiddenfielf like this: form["ctl00$MainContent$myid"]